# Weird behavior of <lightning-record-edit-form> in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

In my LWC, I update two fields of a custom object through a modal. The `<lightning-record-edit-form>` updates only one field (multiselect picklist) and not the other (checkbox). I have the required privileges to update the checkbox field. The `OnSuccess()` function is also called which means there is no error.

Screenshot of LWC. Field 1 = `Contact Role` (1st field) and field 2 = `Is Primary` (Last field)
[image: Screenshot of LWC]

Screenshot of Modal (opens on pressing edit button of datatable)
[image: Screenshot of Modal]

If I make changes to both fields, `Contact Role` changes are updated and `Primary Account` changes are not updated.

Weird thing is, the modal stores the change made for both fields (next time I open the modal, it shows new values) but does not update checkbox field in database. I have a trigger on the checkbox field which does not fire. `Contact Role` field does not face any such issue.

I checked the api name and did debugging but didn't find any mistake. I am not using any custom `OnSubmit()` functionality. Why does `<lightning-record-edit-form>` update one field and not the other?

### Debug

[image: Debug]

### HTML

```html
        <div class="slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-scrollable slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={addresses} columns={columns} onrowaction={handleRowActions}></lightning-datatable>
        </div>

                    <div class="slds-theme_default slds-scrollable" if:true={showEditModal}>
                        <lightning-record-edit-form layout-type="Full"
                            object-api-name="AP_Customer_Relationship__c" record-id={currentRecordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                                <lightning-output-field field-name="Account_ID__c"></lightning-output-field>
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="Contact_Role__c"></lightning-input-field>
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="Primary_Account__c"></lightning-input-field>
                                <br />
                                <div style="text-align:center;">
                                    <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update"
                                        label="Update Record"></lightning-button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </lightning-record-edit-form>
                        <br />
                    </div>
```

### JavaScript

```js
const columns = [
    {
        // label: 'Action',
        type: 'button',
        initialWidth: 50,
        typeAttributes: {
            // label: {fieldName: 'nameMdmId'},
            label: 'Edit',
            variant: 'base',
        }
    },
    { label: 'Contact Role', fieldName: 'Contact_Role', type: 'text', editable:'true' },
    { label: 'Account', fieldName: 'Account_Name', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Segmentation', fieldName: 'Segmentation', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'MDM ID', fieldName: 'Account_MDM_Id', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Account Category', fieldName: 'Account_Category', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Account Subcategory', fieldName: 'Account_Subcategory', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Salesrep', fieldName: 'Sales_Rep', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'IsPrimary', fieldName: 'Is_Primary', type: 'boolean', editable:'true' },
];


export default class ContactRelatedAccount extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track columns = columns;
    @track currentRecordId;
    @track addresses;
    @track record = [];
    selectedRecords = [];
    refreshTable;
    res;

//Getting data from wire and flattening it out
    @wire(getAddress, { LeadID: '$recordId' }) wired(result) {
        this.refreshTable = result;
        if (result.data) {
            let preparedAddresses = [];
            result.data.forEach(address => {
            let preparedAddress = {};
            preparedAddress.Contact_Role = address.ContactRole;
            preparedAddress.Account_Name = address.AccountId.Name;
            preparedAddress.Segmentation = address.AccountId.Segmentation__c;
            preparedAddress.Account_MDM_Id = address.AccountId.Master_Customer_ID__c;
            preparedAddress.Account_Category = address.AccountId.Customer_Category__c;
            preparedAddress.Account_Subcategory = address.AccountId.Customer_Subcategory__c;
            preparedAddress.Sales_Rep = address.salesRep;
            preparedAddresses.push(preparedAddress);
            });
            this.addresses = preparedAddresses;
        }
        if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
        }
    }



    handleRowActions(event) {
        this.row = event.detail.row;
        this.showEditModal = true;
        this.bShowModal = true;
        this.currentRecordId = this.row.CRId;
    }

    // refreshing the datatable after record edit form success
    handleSuccess() {
        this.bShowModal = false;
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success!!',
            message: 'Updated Successfully!!.',
            variant: 'success'
        }));
        return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating that field using execute anonymous to see if the field is updatable?

Comment: @CalvinOKeefe Yes, the field is updatable.There's a trigger which fires on updating the field.